# How to send the data from @property field to database tables in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a DocumentModel containing some fields including document which is a filefield.
I have used @property decorator to get the name, size and mime type of a file which gets uploaded.

The issue that currently i am facing is that @property fields are being shown on frontend in serializers,
but its not being show in database tables.

In database tables only id, document, and created_at is being shown but not filename, filesize, and mimetype

Kindly if someone can guide how can i send this @property data to database tables?

Models.py

```
class DocumentModel(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True, verbose_name="DOCUMENT_ID")
    document=models.FileField(max_length=350 ,validators=  [FileExtensionValidator(extensions)])
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Documents"
        ordering=["document"]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.document}'
    @property
    def filename(self):
        return self.document.name

   

    @property
    def mimetype(self):
        return mimetypes.guess_type(self.document.url)[0]
```

serializers.py

```
class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    
            
        

    class Meta:
        model=DocumentModel
        fields = ['id', 'document', 'filesize', 'filename', 'mimetype', 'created_at']
```

Comment: Properties are *never* shown in the database: properties are determined on-demand: so when you fetch the attribute.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem is there any alternative for what i am doing? like get the property and show it on database tables?

Comment: It makes no sense to do that: the properties are *fully functional dependent* on other fields, so that means it would only introduce *data duplication*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i understand, it does acutally creates data duplication

Comment: @AbdullahRoshan Data duplication by itself is not necessarily bad. If you win in some other way, like in speed for some reason, the trade-off may be worth it. It just introduces a bunch of possible problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create fields in your model instead of properties. These will be mapped to the database. Not sure that is a good idea though. You will need to be very careful to ensure data integrity, when changing files. If you are absolutely sure that is what you want/need, you can e.g. [override the `save` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) to automatically generate the `filename` and `mimetype` field values before saving to the database. Beware thought that the `save` method is **NOT** called when you call [`.objects.update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#update) for example.

Something like this would be possible:

```py
class DocumentModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True, verbose_name="DOCUMENT_ID")
    document = models.FileField(max_length=350 ,validators=  [FileExtensionValidator(extensions)])
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    filename = models.CharField(...)
    mimetype = models.CharField(...)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        self.filename = self.document.name
        self.mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(self.document.url)[0]
        super().save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
```